# Images on SharePoint not loading after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, sharepoint

I am retrieving user profile pictures from SharePoint then displaying those users on a page, settings the `src` attribute in `img` element to the url of the image.

It works perfectly when debugging in VS.

However, after I publish to Azure, the images are not loading. What is strange is that after I click on the link for the image, it seems to authenticate me, and then the images DO start loading...

How can I just pass in the current users credentials automatically so my users don't have to navigate to the image itself before seeing them in the web app?

example of an element:

```
<img src="https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com:443/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/firstname_lastname_company_com_MThumb.jpg?t=63655312814" class="userPic">
```

The currently signed in user is obviously trusted, as it does work after going to that url - can't I add a paramater of some kind to that address to do it automatically?

Really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

With Azure storage, if an image has been saved as private then it will require a sharedaccesssignature.

For any images i have for my own sites i have a class like the below:

```
public string GetAzureStoreImage(string fileName, string containerName)
{
        string imageUrl = string.Empty;

        // Connect to cloud storage account
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("YourStoredConnectionString"));

        // Connect blob client
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Connect to container
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

        // Get reference for current file
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        if (blob.Exists())
        {
            // Create access token for file share
            var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            }, new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
            {
                ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=" + fileName
            });

            // Collect url and download file
            imageUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri, sasToken);
        }

        return imageUrl;
}
```

You will need to include the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob references for them, but this will give a temporary 10 minute token to access the file that will then allow the returned "imageurl" to be your images source.

Finally the fileName is just the filename you would like to collect from your Azure storage, and the containerName is what "bucket" houses the current file.

You may also need to pass in another parameter based on the current users information if they all have their own security tokens to access images which should be appended to your connection string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rando. How do I get that connection string? Is it available in the azure portal?

Comment: Yep, so you can do 2 options for connection string, you can either parse it in the function itself (generally bad practice) and will look something like:
const string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
or depending on your IDE you can add your storage account as a connected service to your project (when you add services theres a specific option to connect directly to your Azure Storage account)

Comment: Thanks rando, I have 1 more question regarding "bucket" and "filename". I only have the url to the image - does that contain both of those elements?

Comment: Hey @Bassie the url makes it tricky, the way the Azure service works is more like a file server (sort of like your windows file explorer) where the bucketName is your folder structure (or like your c: etc.) and your filename is the file itself. If your url contains the filename you can do a string extraction to pull out just the filelocation and push that into it. You will need to find out your bucketname, if you only have one bucket then you can just hardset this in the function instead of passing it in

Comment: Your filename would then be User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/firstname_lastname_company_com_MThumb.jpg (based on the link in your question above), so you would need to break your filename up to only extract that portion of the string.

Comment: So do I need to upload all the images to an azure container? Or can I just use the blob to access the images?

Comment: If they're already in azure, then they should already be housed in a container, it will likely just be the one container name but, if you have access to your azure document storage, go into that, then select your blob service, the first items to show up will be your container names available. Its likely you only have one, in which case thats easy, just hard set that in your function, otherwise you will need to work out which container these images are stored in.

Comment: It seems that either the files aren't stored in a container, or I don't have access the where they are stored.. I don't understand why it needs to be so complicated - I've already authorised my app and can view the images - its just not passing the credentials over

Comment: The reason it has to be complicated is pretty much security. With more security come better hackers and more ways to get data out. If you dont mind the images to be viewed by others you can make all images uploaded publically accessible, otherwise Azure requires Shared access tokens to be generated on every use.

Comment: But the user viewing the website has already been authorised against our domain. And once the image is navigated to outside of the browser, then all the imgaes load for that session... What I mean is that it seems inconsistent to say that the images are blocked for security reasons, but then A) the user is allowed to view, and B) that user can see the images anyways by just navigating to the file directly. I feel like there must be another way to trigger whatever is happing after navigating to the image link, if only I could figure out what is happening at that stage..